Header files in MPLAB X IDE(window 11) with XC8 compiler
Unable to create header files in MPLAB  X IDE IN v6.20 with XC8 compiler in window 11enter image description here
As am using the XC8 compiler tried to add the header file but no option in MPLAB X IDE v6.20 in window 11[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/rB5IrLkZ.png)
even in the existing files I didn't find the header file
The pic controller am using is pic16f877a
